# RAM size mismatch: CPU-Z vs BIOS & Windows

Tags: windows-7, memory, dual-channel

Originally, I had 4GB of RAM (4*1GB), and everything worked like a charm.
A few months ago one of my memory cards got bad, so I had to take it out and throw it away.

A few days ago I bought 2 new identical cards and installed them,
so there are 2*1GB of one manufacturer (kingston), and 2*1GB of another (CEON).
In total it should bring me back to 4GB dual channel.

CPU-Z reports they are all installed ([CPU-Z report](http://www.ashkelonim.co.il/dima-temp/DIMA-PC.html)),
but when BIOS is starting it shows 3145728K, and windows also recognizes only 3GB ([system information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qERK.jpg)).

So... Where's the problem?

Comment: I thought this was going to be an easy question.  32 bit system.  NOT.  1 bad RAM module.  NOT.

Comment: @fixer1234 - What?

Comment: Which ones did you JUST add, the Kingston or the CEON? What motherboard make and model are you using?

Comment: IF you use just the new RAM, does all 2GB show up as expected?

Comment: You should test the RAM modules one by one and possibly the slots one by one.

Answer (score -2):

`Due to an architectural decision made long ago, if you have 4GB of physical RAM installed, Windows is only able to report a portion of the physical 4GB of RAM (ranges from ~2.75GB to 3.5GB depending on the devices installed, motherboard's chipset & BIOS).`

`This behavior is due to "memory mapped IO reservations". Those reservations overlay the physical address space and mask out those physical addresses so that they cannot be used for working memory. This is independent of the OS running on the machine.`

Quoted from: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hiltonl/archive/2007/04/13/the-3gb-not-4gb-ram-problem.aspx

From the CPUZ factsheet,  the mobo is i945. Read more: https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=123711.0

In simple words: `Or, a Windows 64-bit computer may show only 7.1 GB of usable system memory when 8 GB of memory may be installed. This is because usable memory is a calculated amount of the total physical memory minus “hardware reserved” memory.`
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/computer-ram-graphics-card-video-memory

Comment: If I interpret his screenshot correctly, he has a 64-bit version of Windows installed. Memory is remapped, so it’ll remain accessible.

Comment: You made 3 mistakes: It worked with 4GB before, problem shows before OS loads (in POST) and he attached report from 64bit system, while the thing you're linking refers to 32bit Windows.

Comment: @Agent_L please read it care fully first.

Comment: @DanielB please read the post i referred to before downvoting.

Comment: @Agent_L, please learn to count

Comment: All you downvoters atleast read it first.

Comment: We did;  What you quoted has **NOTHING** to do with 64-bit installtion of Windows like the author is using; so your answer is not helpful even in the slightest.  I had the same CPU had no problem using 8GB of memory and before that 4GB of memory

Comment: @Ramhound Please read the second paragraph of the summary on the first blog post and then go through the Intel datasheet given with the second blog post

Comment: I did not downvote and I also *never* heard of problems with remapping (ie. 7.1 GiB available). It’s a standard feature these days, maybe this happens on *very* old mainboards.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 i JUST added the Kingston. I don't think it's relevant though, because I have 5 different sticks now, and any combination of any sticks results in the same behavior - they all work, until I put 4 sticks together. About the MB-model, it's all in the CPU-Z report: Gigabyte, GA-945GM-S2.

Comment: @pabouk I've done that. They all work, until I populate all 4 slots.